# TFS2010 trying to build a CS file

Tags: build, tfsbuild

We recently switched from TFS2008 to TFS2010, and now one of our build definitions is failing on a strange error:

```
Building project "AAAA.cs".
```

It looks like it's trying to build a CS file.  The file exists within a project, but the project builds locally without errors.  I can't find it referenced anywhere (installer or solution file) as a project.

Groping at this point - does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we needed to install SP1 for VS2008 and the forward compatibility hotfix on the build server.  It's still oddly building a CS file as a project, but the builds are now succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this within the MSBuild log of the TFSBuild log?  Is it possible you've included it in the list of solutions/projects to build in the Build Definition (if using the DefaultTemplate build workflow)?

Comment: All that's included in the build definition is the solution itself.  I'm seeing it in the visual "Build steps" display.  I don't see it in the BuildLog.txt (which is the only artifact I'm seeing left from the build in the drop folder).